# Select value of higher level element in xslt template

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Say I have a xml file like so

```
<Cars>
   <Manufacturer name="Ford">
      <SomeOtherBitOfInfo>DenormaliseMe</SomeOtherBitOfInfo>
      <Model>Granada</Model>
      <Model>Cortina</Model>
      <Model>Capri</Model>
```

And I have a template that matches the Model elements and copies them, like so

```
<xsl:template match="Model">
   <xsl:element name="DenormalisedData"><xsl:value-of select="../SomeOtherBitOfInfo"/></xsl:element>
   <xsl:copy></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

What do I have to put to get the value of SomeOtherBitOfInfo so that I get

```
<DenormalisedData>DenormaliseMe</DenormalisedData><Model>Granada</Model>
<DenormalisedData>DenormaliseMe</DenormalisedData><Model>Cortina</Model>
<DenormalisedData>DenormaliseMe</DenormalisedData><Model>Capri</Model>
```

Because the old ../ syntax doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="Model">
    <DenormalisedData>
        <xsl:value-of select="../SomeOtherBitOfInfo"/>
    </DenormalisedData>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Nice answer :D! You have 17 secs. So I can delete my own.

Comment: @Kirill and empo, Thanks guys. Turns out I had a bit of xpath-default-namespace to do as well, which I chose to omit from my question. Thanks for the sanity check. :)